# remove certain lines from a StringBuffer

Tags: java, split, stringbuffer

A legacy app program has a huge String Buffer (size sometimes upto an Mb) and it is processed sequentially for modifying the contents. I have to implement a change wherein I need to update the string buffer to remove some lines starting with certain specific words. What are the possible ways to implement this ?

Ex:

```
ABC:djfk kdjf kdsjfk#
ABC:jfue eijf iefe# 
DEL:kdjfi efe eei # 
DEL:ieeif dfddf dfdf#
HJU:heuir fwer ouier# 
ABC:dsf erereree ererre #
```

I need to delete lines starting with **DEL**. Splitting the string buffer to string, processing the lines and again joining the strings to create a string buffer would be a bit costly. Pls let me know the possible solutions.

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned legacy: what's available to you? `java.util.Scanner`? `StringBuilder`?

Comment: the application has recently migrated to JDK 1.5 - we just compiled with 1.5 JDK and running the application. So, I believe i can use both Scanner and StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* possible to do this in-place efficiently. You'd have to overwrite the characters in the buffer at the proper intervals, and you'd then logically shorten the buffer with `setLength`. It's going to be quite complex, but it would be in-place and `O(N)`.

The reason why you'd want to overwrite instead of using `delete`/`insert` is because that would be `O(N^2)` instead, because things need to be shifted around unnecessarily.

Doing this out-of-place is quite trivial and `O(N)` but would require a secondary buffer, doubling the space requirement.

---

#### Proof-of-concept

Here's a simple proof-of-concept. `removeIntervals` takes a `StringBuffer` and an `int[][] intervals`. Each `int[]` is assumed to be a pair of `{ start, end }` values (half-open range, exclusive upper bound). In linear time and in-place, these intervals are removed from the `StringBuffer` by a simple `overwrite`. This works when intervals are sorted and non-overlapping, and processed left-to-right.

The buffer is then shortened with `setLength`, cutting off as many characters that were removed.

```
static void overwrite(StringBuffer sb, int dst, int srcFrom, int srcTo) {
    for (int i = srcFrom; i < srcTo; i++) {
        sb.setCharAt(dst++, sb.charAt(i));
    }
}
static int safeGet(int[][] arr, int index, int defaultValue) {
    return (index < arr.length) ? arr[index][0] : defaultValue;
}
static void removeIntervals(StringBuffer sb, int[][] intervals) {
    int dst = safeGet(intervals, 0, 0);
    int removed = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < intervals.length; i++) {
        int start = intervals[i][0];
        int end   = intervals[i][1];
        int nextStart = safeGet(intervals, i+1, sb.length());
        overwrite(sb, dst, end, nextStart);
        removed += end - start;
        dst += nextStart - end;
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - removed);
}
```

Then we can test it as follows:

```
    String text = "01234567890123456789";
    int[][][] tests = {
        { { 0, 5, },
        }, // simple test, removing prefix
        { { 1, 2, }, { 3, 4, }, { 5, 6, }
        }, // multiple infix removals
        { { 3, 7, }, { 18, 20, },
        }, // suffix removal
        {
        }, // no-op
        { { 0, 20 },
        }, // remove whole thing
        { { 7, 10 }, { 10, 13 }, {15, 15 }, 
        }, // adjacent intervals, empty intervals
    };

    for (int[][] test : tests) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(text);
        System.out.printf("> '%s'%n", sb);
        System.out.printf("- %s%n", java.util.Arrays.deepToString(test));
        removeIntervals(sb, test);
        System.out.printf("= '%s'%n%n", sb);
    }
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/nqcC9)):

```
> '01234567890123456789'
- [[0, 5]]
= '567890123456789'

> '01234567890123456789'
- [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
= '02467890123456789'

> '01234567890123456789'
- [[3, 7], [18, 20]]
= '01278901234567'

> '01234567890123456789'
- []
= '01234567890123456789'

> '01234567890123456789'
- [[0, 20]]
= ''

> '01234567890123456789'
- [[7, 10], [10, 13], [15, 15]]
= '01234563456789'
```

---

#### Getting the intervals

In this specific case, the intervals can either be built in a preliminary pass (using `indexOf`), or the whole process *can* be done in one pass if absolutely required. The point is that this can definitely be done in-place in linear time (and if absolutely necessary, in a single-pass).

---

#### An out-of-place solution

This is out-of-place using a secondary buffer and regex. It's offered for consideration due to its simplicity. Unless further optimization is provably required (after evidentiary profiling results), this should be good enough:

```
    String text =
        "DEL: line1\n" +
        "KEP: line2\r\n" +
        "DEL: line3\n" +
        "KEP: line4\r" +
        "DEL: line5\r" +
        "DEL: line6\r" +
        "KEP: line7\n" +
        "DEL: line8";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(text);
    Pattern delLine = Pattern.compile("(?m)^DEL:.*$");
    String cleanedUp = delLine.matcher(sb).replaceAll("<deleted!>");
    System.out.println(cleanedUp);
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/g641V)):

```
<deleted!>
KEP: line2
<deleted!>
KEP: line4
<deleted!>
<deleted!>
KEP: line7
<deleted!>
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 2):

> Splitting the string buffer to string,
>   processing the lines and again joining
>   the strings to create a string buffer
>   would be a bit costly.

Removing the lines would actually be *much more* costly, because you'd end up copying the rest of the buffer for each line you remove.

The fastest way would probably be [java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) to get a copy of the buffer without all the lines you don't want.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines in the stringbuffer are separated by newlines, you could read it in and create a new buffer.  For a 1 meg buffer this completes in tens of milliseconds and is faster than a Regex.  You could create a custom version of StringReader to directly read the StringBuffer rather than convert to string to save a little bit more time.

```
final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
StringBuffer nuBuffer = new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(sbData.toString()));
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.startsWith("DEL:")) {  // don't copy lines starting with DEL:
        nuBuffer.append(line).append(NEWLINE);
    }
}
br.close();
```